# How to make a script toggle between two commands when it is executed?

Tags: scripting, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, vlc, audacity

I am trying to write a script file and invoke it using XFCE global shortcut. The script should continue the Audacity application if it is in the stopped state and stop it (pause recording) if it is in the run state. This will be useful when I have defined the same keyboard shortcut for VLC's playback/pause. This way, I can do playback/pause (in VLC) and record/pause (in Audacity) at the same time using the same keyboard shortcut. Getting some ideas from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855893/is-it-possible-to-control-the-recording-if-audacity-is-running-in-the-background) I have written the following script and added it to XFCE's custom keyboard settings. But it does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash 
if pgrep -f "audacity" ;
    then
       pkill -stop audacity && notify-send "Recording stopped"
    else
       pkill -cont audacity
```

Comment: You are missing a `fi` to close the `if` statement. After you fix it, try to run this script in the terminal to see if it outputs any messages.

Comment: It does not work yet after fixing the typo.  It only executes the same command every time (only stops audacity)

Comment: That's because `pgrep` only verifies if there is a process named `audcity`, not if it is running or stopped. So it will always enter the `then` case.

Comment: But honestly I'm not sure that this should work. I don't know how Audacity will handle a SIGSTOP, but the most likely scenario is that you'll stop Audacity as a whole, not just its recording. A better solution would be to use Audacity tools for automation. I think they do exist: http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Automation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to know whether to send the STOP or the CONT signal to the process, you will have to figure out its current state first.

- If it's stopped, you should send CONT.
- If it's not stopped, you should send STOP.

The state of a running process may be found with `ps`. If a process is stopped, then it its state, as reported by `ps -ostate=` will contain the letter `T` (the equal sign will stop `ps` from outputting a header).

```
#!/bin/bash

command="audacity"

pids="$( pgrep "$command" )"

if [[ -z "$pids" ]]; then
    printf '"%s" is not running\n' "$command" >&2
    exit 1
fi

for pid in $pids; do
    state="$( ps -ostate= -p "$pid" )"

    stopped=0

    case "$state" in
        *T*)    stopped=1 ;;
    esac

    if (( stopped )); then
        kill -s CONT "$pid"
        printf '"%s" (%d) has been unpaused\n' "$command" "$pid"
    else
        kill -s STOP "$pid"
        printf '"%s" (%d) has been paused\n' "$command" "$pid"
    fi
done
```

There is a theoretical race-condition in the script whereby the command may have quit between the call to `pgrep` and the call to `kill`.  All that will happen in that case is that `kill` will complain about "no such process".

Comment: Thanks I was kind of dying for a bash solution.  By the last part,  do you mean I cannot pause and unpause two apps at tge same time?

Comment: @JasonStack It's a simple limitation that I didn't notice as I was writing the script. If two processes with the same name are running, `$pid` will get the value of both of them (a string with two numbers), and the `ps` call will probably fail, as will the `kill` call. Hold on, I'll fix it... Done.

Comment: Thanks! I just tested this. It works. However there is some delay between when the script is run and when vlc pauses stops playing or when resumes playing. I experienced the same issue when running a similar script but written in Python by user [Jacob Vlijm](http://askubuntu.com/users/72216/jacob-vlijm) for [this post on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/855893/is-it-possible-to-control-the-recording-if-audacity-is-running-in-the-background/855904).